# What's the deal with char.GetNumericValue?

Tags: .net, unicode, char, numbers

I was working on [Project Euler 40](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=40), and was a bit bothered that there was no `int.Parse(char)`.  Not a big deal, but I did some asking around and someone suggested `char.GetNumericValue`.  `GetNumericValue` seems like a very odd method to me:

- Takes in a char as a parameter and returns... a double?
- Returns -1.0 if the char is not '0' through '9'

So what's the reasoning behind this method, and what purpose does returning a double serve?  I even fired up Reflector and looked at `InternalGetNumericValue`, but it's just like watching Lost: every answer just leads to another question.

Comment: Note that if you just want to convert a digit to an int, `int.Parse(c.ToString())` would work fine. No reason to use GetNumericValue unless you're in the situation that Adam Sills describes. Or, of course, just subtracting `'0'` from the char.

Comment: Yeah, and that's what I'm actually using, but converting to a string and then parsing into an int seems a little wordy and/or excessive.  I could also subtract '0' from the char of course, but that seems a little 'magic string'y

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Remember that it's taking a Unicode character and returning a value. '0' through '9' are the standard decimal digits, however there are other Unicode characters that represent numbers, some of which are floating point.

Like this character: ¼

```
Console.WriteLine( char.GetNumericValue( '¼' ) );
```

Outputs 0.25 in the console window.

Answer (score 41):

Here is a comprehensive list of actual numeric values that are returned:

```
0 - 0   1 - 1   2 - 2   3 - 3   4 - 4   5 - 5   6 - 6   7 - 7   8 - 8   9 - 9   
² - 2   ³ - 3   ¹ - 1   ¼ - 0.25    ½ - 0.5 ¾ - 0.75    ٠ - 0   ١ - 1   ٢ - 2   ٣ - 3   
٤ - 4   ٥ - 5   ٦ - 6   ٧ - 7   ٨ - 8   ٩ - 9   ۰ - 0   ۱ - 1   ۲ - 2   ۳ - 3   
۴ - 4   ۵ - 5   ۶ - 6   ۷ - 7   ۸ - 8   ۹ - 9   ߀ - 0   ߁ - 1   ߂ - 2   ߃ - 3   
߄ - 4   ߅ - 5   ߆ - 6   ߇ - 7   ߈ - 8   ߉ - 9   ० - 0   १ - 1   २ - 2   ३ - 3   
४ - 4   ५ - 5   ६ - 6   ७ - 7   ८ - 8   ९ - 9   ০ - 0   ১ - 1   ২ - 2   ৩ - 3   
৪ - 4   ৫ - 5   ৬ - 6   ৭ - 7   ৮ - 8   ৯ - 9   ৴ - 1   ৵ - 2   ৶ - 3   ৷ - 4   
৹ - 16  ੦ - 0   ੧ - 1   ੨ - 2   ੩ - 3   ੪ - 4   ੫ - 5   ੬ - 6   ੭ - 7   ੮ - 8   
੯ - 9   ૦ - 0   ૧ - 1   ૨ - 2   ૩ - 3   ૪ - 4   ૫ - 5   ૬ - 6   ૭ - 7   ૮ - 8   
૯ - 9   ୦ - 0   ୧ - 1   ୨ - 2   ୩ - 3   ୪ - 4   ୫ - 5   ୬ - 6   ୭ - 7   ୮ - 8   
୯ - 9   ௦ - 0   ௧ - 1   ௨ - 2   ௩ - 3   ௪ - 4   ௫ - 5   ௬ - 6   ௭ - 7   ௮ - 8   
௯ - 9   ௰ - 10  ௱ - 100 ௲ - 1000    ౦ - 0   ౧ - 1   ౨ - 2   ౩ - 3   ౪ - 4   ౫ - 5   
౬ - 6   ౭ - 7   ౮ - 8   ౯ - 9   ೦ - 0   ೧ - 1   ೨ - 2   ೩ - 3   ೪ - 4   ೫ - 5   
೬ - 6   ೭ - 7   ೮ - 8   ೯ - 9   ൦ - 0   ൧ - 1   ൨ - 2   ൩ - 3   ൪ - 4   ൫ - 5   
൬ - 6   ൭ - 7   ൮ - 8   ൯ - 9   ๐ - 0   ๑ - 1   ๒ - 2   ๓ - 3   ๔ - 4   ๕ - 5   
๖ - 6   ๗ - 7   ๘ - 8   ๙ - 9   ໐ - 0   ໑ - 1   ໒ - 2   ໓ - 3   ໔ - 4   ໕ - 5   
໖ - 6   ໗ - 7   ໘ - 8   ໙ - 9   ༠ - 0   ༡ - 1   ༢ - 2   ༣ - 3   ༤ - 4   ༥ - 5   
༦ - 6   ༧ - 7   ༨ - 8   ༩ - 9   ༪ - 0.5 ༫ - 1.5 ༬ - 2.5 ༭ - 3.5 ༮ - 4.5 ༯ - 5.5 
༰ - 6.5 ༱ - 7.5 ༲ - 8.5 ༳ - -0.5    ၀ - 0   ၁ - 1   ၂ - 2   ၃ - 3   ၄ - 4   ၅ - 5   
၆ - 6   ၇ - 7   ၈ - 8   ၉ - 9   ፩ - 1   ፪ - 2   ፫ - 3   ፬ - 4   ፭ - 5   ፮ - 6   
፯ - 7   ፰ - 8   ፱ - 9   ፲ - 10  ፳ - 20  ፴ - 30  ፵ - 40  ፶ - 50  ፷ - 60  ፸ - 70  
፹ - 80  ፺ - 90  ፻ - 100 ፼ - 10000   ᛮ - 17  ᛯ - 18  ᛰ - 19  ០ - 0   ១ - 1   ២ - 2   
៣ - 3   ៤ - 4   ៥ - 5   ៦ - 6   ៧ - 7   ៨ - 8   ៩ - 9   ៰ - 0   ៱ - 1   ៲ - 2   
៳ - 3   ៴ - 4   ៵ - 5   ៶ - 6   ៷ - 7   ៸ - 8   ៹ - 9   ᠐ - 0   ᠑ - 1   ᠒ - 2   
᠓ - 3   ᠔ - 4   ᠕ - 5   ᠖ - 6   ᠗ - 7   ᠘ - 8   ᠙ - 9   ᥆ - 0   ᥇ - 1   ᥈ - 2   
᥉ - 3   ᥊ - 4   ᥋ - 5   ᥌ - 6   ᥍ - 7   ᥎ - 8   ᥏ - 9   ᧐ - 0   ᧑ - 1   ᧒ - 2   
᧓ - 3   ᧔ - 4   ᧕ - 5   ᧖ - 6   ᧗ - 7   ᧘ - 8   ᧙ - 9   ᭐ - 0   ᭑ - 1   ᭒ - 2   
᭓ - 3   ᭔ - 4   ᭕ - 5   ᭖ - 6   ᭗ - 7   ᭘ - 8   ᭙ - 9   ⁰ - 0   ⁴ - 4   ⁵ - 5   
⁶ - 6   ⁷ - 7   ⁸ - 8   ⁹ - 9   ₀ - 0   ₁ - 1   ₂ - 2   ₃ - 3   ₄ - 4   ₅ - 5   
₆ - 6   ₇ - 7   ₈ - 8   ₉ - 9   ⅓ - 0.333333333333333   ⅔ - 0.666666666666667   ⅕ - 0.2 ⅖ - 0.4 ⅗ - 0.6 ⅘ - 0.8 
⅙ - 0.166666666666667   ⅚ - 0.833333333333333   ⅛ - 0.125   ⅜ - 0.375   ⅝ - 0.625   ⅞ - 0.875   ⅟ - 1   Ⅰ - 1   Ⅱ - 2   Ⅲ - 3   
Ⅳ - 4   Ⅴ - 5   Ⅵ - 6   Ⅶ - 7   Ⅷ - 8   Ⅸ - 9   Ⅹ - 10  Ⅺ - 11  Ⅻ - 12  Ⅼ - 50  
Ⅽ - 100 Ⅾ - 500 Ⅿ - 1000    ⅰ - 1   ⅱ - 2   ⅲ - 3   ⅳ - 4   ⅴ - 5   ⅵ - 6   ⅶ - 7   
ⅷ - 8   ⅸ - 9   ⅹ - 10  ⅺ - 11  ⅻ - 12  ⅼ - 50  ⅽ - 100 ⅾ - 500 ⅿ - 1000    ↀ - 1000    
ↁ - 5000    ↂ - 10000   ① - 1   ② - 2   ③ - 3   ④ - 4   ⑤ - 5   ⑥ - 6   ⑦ - 7   ⑧ - 8   
⑨ - 9   ⑩ - 10  ⑪ - 11  ⑫ - 12  ⑬ - 13  ⑭ - 14  ⑮ - 15  ⑯ - 16  ⑰ - 17  ⑱ - 18  
⑲ - 19  ⑳ - 20  ⑴ - 1   ⑵ - 2   ⑶ - 3   ⑷ - 4   ⑸ - 5   ⑹ - 6   ⑺ - 7   ⑻ - 8   
⑼ - 9   ⑽ - 10  ⑾ - 11  ⑿ - 12  ⒀ - 13  ⒁ - 14  ⒂ - 15  ⒃ - 16  ⒄ - 17  ⒅ - 18  
⒆ - 19  ⒇ - 20  ⒈ - 1   ⒉ - 2   ⒊ - 3   ⒋ - 4   ⒌ - 5   ⒍ - 6   ⒎ - 7   ⒏ - 8   
⒐ - 9   ⒑ - 10  ⒒ - 11  ⒓ - 12  ⒔ - 13  ⒕ - 14  ⒖ - 15  ⒗ - 16  ⒘ - 17  ⒙ - 18  
⒚ - 19  ⒛ - 20  ⓪ - 0   ⓫ - 11  ⓬ - 12  ⓭ - 13  ⓮ - 14  ⓯ - 15  ⓰ - 16  ⓱ - 17  
⓲ - 18  ⓳ - 19  ⓴ - 20  ⓵ - 1   ⓶ - 2   ⓷ - 3   ⓸ - 4   ⓹ - 5   ⓺ - 6   ⓻ - 7   
⓼ - 8   ⓽ - 9   ⓾ - 10  ⓿ - 0   ❶ - 1   ❷ - 2   ❸ - 3   ❹ - 4   ❺ - 5   ❻ - 6   
❼ - 7   ❽ - 8   ❾ - 9   ❿ - 10  ➀ - 1   ➁ - 2   ➂ - 3   ➃ - 4   ➄ - 5   ➅ - 6   
➆ - 7   ➇ - 8   ➈ - 9   ➉ - 10  ➊ - 1   ➋ - 2   ➌ - 3   ➍ - 4   ➎ - 5   ➏ - 6   
➐ - 7   ➑ - 8   ➒ - 9   ➓ - 10  ⳽ - 0.5 〇 - 0   〡 - 1   〢 - 2   〣 - 3   〤 - 4   
〥 - 5   〦 - 6   〧 - 7   〨 - 8   〩 - 9   〸 - 10  〹 - 20  〺 - 30  ㆒ - 1   ㆓ - 2   
㆔ - 3   ㆕ - 4   ㈠ - 1   ㈡ - 2   ㈢ - 3   ㈣ - 4   ㈤ - 5   ㈥ - 6   ㈦ - 7   ㈧ - 8   
㈨ - 9   ㈩ - 10  ㉑ - 21  ㉒ - 22  ㉓ - 23  ㉔ - 24  ㉕ - 25  ㉖ - 26  ㉗ - 27  ㉘ - 28  
㉙ - 29  ㉚ - 30  ㉛ - 31  ㉜ - 32  ㉝ - 33  ㉞ - 34  ㉟ - 35  ㊀ - 1   ㊁ - 2   ㊂ - 3   
㊃ - 4   ㊄ - 5   ㊅ - 6   ㊆ - 7   ㊇ - 8   ㊈ - 9   ㊉ - 10  ㊱ - 36  ㊲ - 37  ㊳ - 38  
㊴ - 39  ㊵ - 40  ㊶ - 41  ㊷ - 42  ㊸ - 43  ㊹ - 44  ㊺ - 45  ㊻ - 46  ㊼ - 47  ㊽ - 48  
㊾ - 49  ㊿ - 50  ０ - 0   １ - 1   ２ - 2   ３ - 3   ４ - 4   ５ - 5   ６ - 6   ７ - 7   
８ - 8   ９ - 9
```

Comment: Holy crap! Where'd you get this?

Comment: Looks like `for( char c = 1; c <= char.MaxValue; c++ )`

Comment: Disappointed that Pi is only classified as a letter and not a number.

Comment: @Adam Sills: Me too, but then you would also have to let in at least e, and depending on their popularity, maybe others like rho.

Comment: And if you allowed e, you might have to allow i, and then even `float` is no longer an adequate return type!

Comment: @AdamSills `e` doesn't belong to the Number category defined by the standard. `char.GetNumericValue()` just do exactly what the Unicode standard says. And running from 1 to `char.MaxValue` like that won't return all the possible values since some number are outside the BMP

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode Consortium maintains a list of characters called [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/) with the main file describing characters is [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt). Each character belongs to a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) and has a number of [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property). So **if a character belongs to category *Number*, and has the property *Numeric_Type* then it's a numeric value**, and `char.GetNumericValue()` will return that value. You can check that value in UnicodeData.txt, if the corresponding code point is numeric there will be many related fields in the line. For example for U+109BC you can see this, which means it represents ¹¹⁄ ₁₂:

```
109BC;MEROITIC CURSIVE FRACTION ELEVEN TWELFTHS;No;0;R;;;;11/12;N;;;;;
```

Notice the `11/12` field near the end. A more detailed numeric description can be found in [DerivedNumericType.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedNumericType.txt). One example line of it:

```
11FC0..11FD4  ; Numeric # No  [21] TAMIL FRACTION ONE THREE-HUNDRED-AND-TWENTIETH..TAMIL FRACTION DOWNSCALING FACTOR KIIZH
```

For more detailed information read

- [Numeric Property Definitions](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2012/12310-numeric-type-def.html)
- [Unicode® Standard Annex #44 - Numeric_Type](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Numeric_Type)

---

So as you can see, the list in John Rasch's answer is *far from comprehensive* because only numbers in the BMP are listed. So I wrote the following small program to print all numeric code points including the ones outside the BMP

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        int c = 0;
        // Print from i = 1 for all the possible numbers,
        //            i = 0x10000 for numbers outside the BMP
        for (int i = 0x10000; i < 0x10FFFF; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var ch = char.ConvertFromUtf32(i);
                var numericValue = char.GetNumericValue(ch, 0);
                if (numericValue != -1)
                {
                    Console.Write("|U+{0:X5} ({1}): {2}", i, ch, numericValue);
                    if (c == 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("|");
                        c = 0;
                    }
                    else
                        c++;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the initial value of the loop to get all numeric values

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 so [Unicode 11.0 will be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#strings-and-the-unicode-standard). If you run it in .NET 5 you'll get Unicode 13.0 output, and later versions may have more digits

Here the program's the output in Unicode 11.0:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+10107 (): 1 | U+10108 (): 2 | U+10109 (): 3 | U+1010A (): 4 | U+1010B (): 5 |
| U+1010C (): 6 | U+1010D (): 7 | U+1010E (): 8 | U+1010F (): 9 | U+10110 (): 10 |
| U+10111 (): 20 | U+10112 (): 30 | U+10113 (): 40 | U+10114 (): 50 | U+10115 (): 60 |
| U+10116 (): 70 | U+10117 (): 80 | U+10118 (): 90 | U+10119 (): 100 | U+1011A (): 200 |
| U+1011B (): 300 | U+1011C (): 400 | U+1011D (): 500 | U+1011E (): 600 | U+1011F (): 700 |
| U+10120 (): 800 | U+10121 (): 900 | U+10122 (): 1000 | U+10123 (): 2000 | U+10124 (): 3000 |
| U+10125 (): 4000 | U+10126 (): 5000 | U+10127 (): 6000 | U+10128 (): 7000 | U+10129 (): 8000 |
| U+1012A (): 9000 | U+1012B (): 10000 | U+1012C (): 20000 | U+1012D (): 30000 | U+1012E (): 40000 |
| U+1012F (): 50000 | U+10130 (): 60000 | U+10131 (): 70000 | U+10132 (): 80000 | U+10133 (): 90000 |
| U+10140 (): 0.25 | U+10141 (): 0.5 | U+10142 (): 1 | U+10143 (): 5 | U+10144 (): 50 |
| U+10145 (): 500 | U+10146 (): 5000 | U+10147 (): 50000 | U+10148 (): 5 | U+10149 (): 10 |
| U+1014A (): 50 | U+1014B (): 100 | U+1014C (): 500 | U+1014D (): 1000 | U+1014E (): 5000 |
| U+1014F (): 5 | U+10150 (): 10 | U+10151 (): 50 | U+10152 (): 100 | U+10153 (): 500 |
| U+10154 (): 1000 | U+10155 (): 10000 | U+10156 (): 50000 | U+10157 (): 10 | U+10158 (): 1 |
| U+10159 (): 1 | U+1015A (): 1 | U+1015B (): 2 | U+1015C (): 2 | U+1015D (): 2 |
| U+1015E (): 2 | U+1015F (): 5 | U+10160 (): 10 | U+10161 (): 10 | U+10162 (): 10 |
| U+10163 (): 10 | U+10164 (): 10 | U+10165 (): 30 | U+10166 (): 50 | U+10167 (): 50 |
| U+10168 (): 50 | U+10169 (): 50 | U+1016A (): 100 | U+1016B (): 300 | U+1016C (): 500 |
| U+1016D (): 500 | U+1016E (): 500 | U+1016F (): 500 | U+10170 (): 500 | U+10171 (): 1000 |
| U+10172 (): 5000 | U+10173 (): 5 | U+10174 (): 50 | U+10175 (): 0.5 | U+10176 (): 0.5 |
| U+10177 (): 0.6666666666666666 | U+10178 (): 0.75 | U+1018A (): 0 | U+1018B (): 0.25 | U+102E1 (): 1 |
| U+102E2 (): 2 | U+102E3 (): 3 | U+102E4 (): 4 | U+102E5 (): 5 | U+102E6 (): 6 |
| U+102E7 (): 7 | U+102E8 (): 8 | U+102E9 (): 9 | U+102EA (): 10 | U+102EB (): 20 |
| U+102EC (): 30 | U+102ED (): 40 | U+102EE (): 50 | U+102EF (): 60 | U+102F0 (): 70 |
| U+102F1 (): 80 | U+102F2 (): 90 | U+102F3 (): 100 | U+102F4 (): 200 | U+102F5 (): 300 |
| U+102F6 (): 400 | U+102F7 (): 500 | U+102F8 (): 600 | U+102F9 (): 700 | U+102FA (): 800 |
| U+102FB (): 900 | U+10320 (): 1 | U+10321 (): 5 | U+10322 (): 10 | U+10323 (): 50 |
| U+10341 (): 90 | U+1034A (): 900 | U+103D1 (): 1 | U+103D2 (): 2 | U+103D3 (): 10 |
| U+103D4 (): 20 | U+103D5 (): 100 | U+104A0 (): 0 | U+104A1 (): 1 | U+104A2 (): 2 |
| U+104A3 (): 3 | U+104A4 (): 4 | U+104A5 (): 5 | U+104A6 (): 6 | U+104A7 (): 7 |
| U+104A8 (): 8 | U+104A9 (): 9 | U+10858 (): 1 | U+10859 (): 2 | U+1085A (): 3 |
| U+1085B (): 10 | U+1085C (): 20 | U+1085D (): 100 | U+1085E (): 1000 | U+1085F (): 10000 |
| U+10879 (): 1 | U+1087A (): 2 | U+1087B (): 3 | U+1087C (): 4 | U+1087D (): 5 |
| U+1087E (): 10 | U+1087F (): 20 | U+108A7 (): 1 | U+108A8 (): 2 | U+108A9 (): 3 |
| U+108AA (): 4 | U+108AB (): 4 | U+108AC (): 5 | U+108AD (): 10 | U+108AE (): 20 |
| U+108AF (): 100 | U+108FB (): 1 | U+108FC (): 5 | U+108FD (): 10 | U+108FE (): 20 |
| U+108FF (): 100 | U+10916 (): 1 | U+10917 (): 10 | U+10918 (): 20 | U+10919 (): 100 |
| U+1091A (): 2 | U+1091B (): 3 | U+109BC (): 0.9166666666666666 | U+109BD (): 0.5 | U+109C0 (): 1 |
| U+109C1 (): 2 | U+109C2 (): 3 | U+109C3 (): 4 | U+109C4 (): 5 | U+109C5 (): 6 |
| U+109C6 (): 7 | U+109C7 (): 8 | U+109C8 (): 9 | U+109C9 (): 10 | U+109CA (): 20 |
| U+109CB (): 30 | U+109CC (): 40 | U+109CD (): 50 | U+109CE (): 60 | U+109CF (): 70 |
| U+109D2 (): 100 | U+109D3 (): 200 | U+109D4 (): 300 | U+109D5 (): 400 | U+109D6 (): 500 |
| U+109D7 (): 600 | U+109D8 (): 700 | U+109D9 (): 800 | U+109DA (): 900 | U+109DB (): 1000 |
| U+109DC (): 2000 | U+109DD (): 3000 | U+109DE (): 4000 | U+109DF (): 5000 | U+109E0 (): 6000 |
| U+109E1 (): 7000 | U+109E2 (): 8000 | U+109E3 (): 9000 | U+109E4 (): 10000 | U+109E5 (): 20000 |
| U+109E6 (): 30000 | U+109E7 (): 40000 | U+109E8 (): 50000 | U+109E9 (): 60000 | U+109EA (): 70000 |
| U+109EB (): 80000 | U+109EC (): 90000 | U+109ED (): 100000 | U+109EE (): 200000 | U+109EF (): 300000 |
| U+109F0 (): 400000 | U+109F1 (): 500000 | U+109F2 (): 600000 | U+109F3 (): 700000 | U+109F4 (): 800000 |
| U+109F5 (): 900000 | U+109F6 (): 0.08333333333333333 | U+109F7 (): 0.16666666666666666 | U+109F8 (): 0.25 | U+109F9 (): 0.3333333333333333 |
| U+109FA (): 0.4166666666666667 | U+109FB (): 0.5 | U+109FC (): 0.5833333333333334 | U+109FD (): 0.6666666666666666 | U+109FE (): 0.75 |
| U+109FF (): 0.8333333333333334 | U+10A40 (): 1 | U+10A41 (): 2 | U+10A42 (): 3 | U+10A43 (): 4 |
| U+10A44 (): 10 | U+10A45 (): 20 | U+10A46 (): 100 | U+10A47 (): 1000 | U+10A48 (): 0.5 |
| U+10A7D (): 1 | U+10A7E (): 50 | U+10A9D (): 1 | U+10A9E (): 10 | U+10A9F (): 20 |
| U+10AEB (): 1 | U+10AEC (): 5 | U+10AED (): 10 | U+10AEE (): 20 | U+10AEF (): 100 |
| U+10B58 (): 1 | U+10B59 (): 2 | U+10B5A (): 3 | U+10B5B (): 4 | U+10B5C (): 10 |
| U+10B5D (): 20 | U+10B5E (): 100 | U+10B5F (): 1000 | U+10B78 (): 1 | U+10B79 (): 2 |
| U+10B7A (): 3 | U+10B7B (): 4 | U+10B7C (): 10 | U+10B7D (): 20 | U+10B7E (): 100 |
| U+10B7F (): 1000 | U+10BA9 (): 1 | U+10BAA (): 2 | U+10BAB (): 3 | U+10BAC (): 4 |
| U+10BAD (): 10 | U+10BAE (): 20 | U+10BAF (): 100 | U+10CFA (): 1 | U+10CFB (): 5 |
| U+10CFC (): 10 | U+10CFD (): 50 | U+10CFE (): 100 | U+10CFF (): 1000 | U+10D30 (): 0 |
| U+10D31 (): 1 | U+10D32 (): 2 | U+10D33 (): 3 | U+10D34 (): 4 | U+10D35 (): 5 |
| U+10D36 (): 6 | U+10D37 (): 7 | U+10D38 (): 8 | U+10D39 (): 9 | U+10E60 (): 1 |
| U+10E61 (): 2 | U+10E62 (): 3 | U+10E63 (): 4 | U+10E64 (): 5 | U+10E65 (): 6 |
| U+10E66 (): 7 | U+10E67 (): 8 | U+10E68 (): 9 | U+10E69 (): 10 | U+10E6A (): 20 |
| U+10E6B (): 30 | U+10E6C (): 40 | U+10E6D (): 50 | U+10E6E (): 60 | U+10E6F (): 70 |
| U+10E70 (): 80 | U+10E71 (): 90 | U+10E72 (): 100 | U+10E73 (): 200 | U+10E74 (): 300 |
| U+10E75 (): 400 | U+10E76 (): 500 | U+10E77 (): 600 | U+10E78 (): 700 | U+10E79 (): 800 |
| U+10E7A (): 900 | U+10E7B (): 0.5 | U+10E7C (): 0.25 | U+10E7D (): 0.3333333333333333 | U+10E7E (): 0.6666666666666666 |
| U+10F1D (): 1 | U+10F1E (): 2 | U+10F1F (): 3 | U+10F20 (): 4 | U+10F21 (): 5 |
| U+10F22 (): 10 | U+10F23 (): 20 | U+10F24 (): 30 | U+10F25 (): 100 | U+10F26 (): 0.5 |
| U+10F51 (): 1 | U+10F52 (): 10 | U+10F53 (): 20 | U+10F54 (): 100 | U+11052 (): 1 |
| U+11053 (): 2 | U+11054 (): 3 | U+11055 (): 4 | U+11056 (): 5 | U+11057 (): 6 |
| U+11058 (): 7 | U+11059 (): 8 | U+1105A (): 9 | U+1105B (): 10 | U+1105C (): 20 |
| U+1105D (): 30 | U+1105E (): 40 | U+1105F (): 50 | U+11060 (): 60 | U+11061 (): 70 |
| U+11062 (): 80 | U+11063 (): 90 | U+11064 (): 100 | U+11065 (): 1000 | U+11066 (): 0 |
| U+11067 (): 1 | U+11068 (): 2 | U+11069 (): 3 | U+1106A (): 4 | U+1106B (): 5 |
| U+1106C (): 6 | U+1106D (): 7 | U+1106E (): 8 | U+1106F (): 9 | U+110F0 (): 0 |
| U+110F1 (): 1 | U+110F2 (): 2 | U+110F3 (): 3 | U+110F4 (): 4 | U+110F5 (): 5 |
| U+110F6 (): 6 | U+110F7 (): 7 | U+110F8 (): 8 | U+110F9 (): 9 | U+11136 (): 0 |
| U+11137 (): 1 | U+11138 (): 2 | U+11139 (): 3 | U+1113A (): 4 | U+1113B (): 5 |
| U+1113C (): 6 | U+1113D (): 7 | U+1113E (): 8 | U+1113F (): 9 | U+111D0 (): 0 |
| U+111D1 (): 1 | U+111D2 (): 2 | U+111D3 (): 3 | U+111D4 (): 4 | U+111D5 (): 5 |
| U+111D6 (): 6 | U+111D7 (): 7 | U+111D8 (): 8 | U+111D9 (): 9 | U+111E1 (): 1 |
| U+111E2 (): 2 | U+111E3 (): 3 | U+111E4 (): 4 | U+111E5 (): 5 | U+111E6 (): 6 |
| U+111E7 (): 7 | U+111E8 (): 8 | U+111E9 (): 9 | U+111EA (): 10 | U+111EB (): 20 |
| U+111EC (): 30 | U+111ED (): 40 | U+111EE (): 50 | U+111EF (): 60 | U+111F0 (): 70 |
| U+111F1 (): 80 | U+111F2 (): 90 | U+111F3 (): 100 | U+111F4 (): 1000 | U+112F0 (): 0 |
| U+112F1 (): 1 | U+112F2 (): 2 | U+112F3 (): 3 | U+112F4 (): 4 | U+112F5 (): 5 |
| U+112F6 (): 6 | U+112F7 (): 7 | U+112F8 (): 8 | U+112F9 (): 9 | U+11450 (): 0 |
| U+11451 (): 1 | U+11452 (): 2 | U+11453 (): 3 | U+11454 (): 4 | U+11455 (): 5 |
| U+11456 (): 6 | U+11457 (): 7 | U+11458 (): 8 | U+11459 (): 9 | U+114D0 (): 0 |
| U+114D1 (): 1 | U+114D2 (): 2 | U+114D3 (): 3 | U+114D4 (): 4 | U+114D5 (): 5 |
| U+114D6 (): 6 | U+114D7 (): 7 | U+114D8 (): 8 | U+114D9 (): 9 | U+11650 (): 0 |
| U+11651 (): 1 | U+11652 (): 2 | U+11653 (): 3 | U+11654 (): 4 | U+11655 (): 5 |
| U+11656 (): 6 | U+11657 (): 7 | U+11658 (): 8 | U+11659 (): 9 | U+116C0 (): 0 |
| U+116C1 (): 1 | U+116C2 (): 2 | U+116C3 (): 3 | U+116C4 (): 4 | U+116C5 (): 5 |
| U+116C6 (): 6 | U+116C7 (): 7 | U+116C8 (): 8 | U+116C9 (): 9 | U+11730 (): 0 |
| U+11731 (): 1 | U+11732 (): 2 | U+11733 (): 3 | U+11734 (): 4 | U+11735 (): 5 |
| U+11736 (): 6 | U+11737 (): 7 | U+11738 (): 8 | U+11739 (): 9 | U+1173A (): 10 |
| U+1173B (): 20 | U+118E0 (): 0 | U+118E1 (): 1 | U+118E2 (): 2 | U+118E3 (): 3 |
| U+118E4 (): 4 | U+118E5 (): 5 | U+118E6 (): 6 | U+118E7 (): 7 | U+118E8 (): 8 |
| U+118E9 (): 9 | U+118EA (): 10 | U+118EB (): 20 | U+118EC (): 30 | U+118ED (): 40 |
| U+118EE (): 50 | U+118EF (): 60 | U+118F0 (): 70 | U+118F1 (): 80 | U+118F2 (): 90 |
| U+11C50 (): 0 | U+11C51 (): 1 | U+11C52 (): 2 | U+11C53 (): 3 | U+11C54 (): 4 |
| U+11C55 (): 5 | U+11C56 (): 6 | U+11C57 (): 7 | U+11C58 (): 8 | U+11C59 (): 9 |
| U+11C5A (): 1 | U+11C5B (): 2 | U+11C5C (): 3 | U+11C5D (): 4 | U+11C5E (): 5 |
| U+11C5F (): 6 | U+11C60 (): 7 | U+11C61 (): 8 | U+11C62 (): 9 | U+11C63 (): 10 |
| U+11C64 (): 20 | U+11C65 (): 30 | U+11C66 (): 40 | U+11C67 (): 50 | U+11C68 (): 60 |
| U+11C69 (): 70 | U+11C6A (): 80 | U+11C6B (): 90 | U+11C6C (): 100 | U+11D50 (): 0 |
| U+11D51 (): 1 | U+11D52 (): 2 | U+11D53 (): 3 | U+11D54 (): 4 | U+11D55 (): 5 |
| U+11D56 (): 6 | U+11D57 (): 7 | U+11D58 (): 8 | U+11D59 (): 9 | U+11DA0 (): 0 |
| U+11DA1 (): 1 | U+11DA2 (): 2 | U+11DA3 (): 3 | U+11DA4 (): 4 | U+11DA5 (): 5 |
| U+11DA6 (): 6 | U+11DA7 (): 7 | U+11DA8 (): 8 | U+11DA9 (): 9 | U+12400 (): 2 |
| U+12401 (): 3 | U+12402 (): 4 | U+12403 (): 5 | U+12404 (): 6 | U+12405 (): 7 |
| U+12406 (): 8 | U+12407 (): 9 | U+12408 (): 3 | U+12409 (): 4 | U+1240A (): 5 |
| U+1240B (): 6 | U+1240C (): 7 | U+1240D (): 8 | U+1240E (): 9 | U+1240F (): 4 |
| U+12410 (): 5 | U+12411 (): 6 | U+12412 (): 7 | U+12413 (): 8 | U+12414 (): 9 |
| U+12415 (): 1 | U+12416 (): 2 | U+12417 (): 3 | U+12418 (): 4 | U+12419 (): 5 |
| U+1241A (): 6 | U+1241B (): 7 | U+1241C (): 8 | U+1241D (): 9 | U+1241E (): 1 |
| U+1241F (): 2 | U+12420 (): 3 | U+12421 (): 4 | U+12422 (): 5 | U+12423 (): 2 |
| U+12424 (): 3 | U+12425 (): 3 | U+12426 (): 4 | U+12427 (): 5 | U+12428 (): 6 |
| U+12429 (): 7 | U+1242A (): 8 | U+1242B (): 9 | U+1242C (): 1 | U+1242D (): 2 |
| U+1242E (): 3 | U+1242F (): 3 | U+12430 (): 4 | U+12431 (): 5 | U+12432 (): 216000 |
| U+12433 (): 432000 | U+12434 (): 1 | U+12435 (): 2 | U+12436 (): 3 | U+12437 (): 3 |
| U+12438 (): 4 | U+12439 (): 5 | U+1243A (): 3 | U+1243B (): 3 | U+1243C (): 4 |
| U+1243D (): 4 | U+1243E (): 4 | U+1243F (): 4 | U+12440 (): 6 | U+12441 (): 7 |
| U+12442 (): 7 | U+12443 (): 7 | U+12444 (): 8 | U+12445 (): 8 | U+12446 (): 9 |
| U+12447 (): 9 | U+12448 (): 9 | U+12449 (): 9 | U+1244A (): 2 | U+1244B (): 3 |
| U+1244C (): 4 | U+1244D (): 5 | U+1244E (): 6 | U+1244F (): 1 | U+12450 (): 2 |
| U+12451 (): 3 | U+12452 (): 4 | U+12453 (): 4 | U+12454 (): 5 | U+12455 (): 5 |
| U+12456 (): 2 | U+12457 (): 3 | U+12458 (): 1 | U+12459 (): 2 | U+1245A (): 0.3333333333333333 |
| U+1245B (): 0.6666666666666666 | U+1245C (): 0.8333333333333334 | U+1245D (): 0.3333333333333333 | U+1245E (): 0.6666666666666666 | U+1245F (): 0.125 |
| U+12460 (): 0.25 | U+12461 (): 0.16666666666666666 | U+12462 (): 0.25 | U+12463 (): 0.25 | U+12464 (): 0.5 |
| U+12465 (): 0.3333333333333333 | U+12466 (): 0.6666666666666666 | U+12467 (): 40 | U+12468 (): 50 | U+12469 (): 4 |
| U+1246A (): 5 | U+1246B (): 6 | U+1246C (): 7 | U+1246D (): 8 | U+1246E (): 9 |
| U+16A60 (): 0 | U+16A61 (): 1 | U+16A62 (): 2 | U+16A63 (): 3 | U+16A64 (): 4 |
| U+16A65 (): 5 | U+16A66 (): 6 | U+16A67 (): 7 | U+16A68 (): 8 | U+16A69 (): 9 |
| U+16B50 (): 0 | U+16B51 (): 1 | U+16B52 (): 2 | U+16B53 (): 3 | U+16B54 (): 4 |
| U+16B55 (): 5 | U+16B56 (): 6 | U+16B57 (): 7 | U+16B58 (): 8 | U+16B59 (): 9 |
| U+16B5B (): 10 | U+16B5C (): 100 | U+16B5D (): 10000 | U+16B5E (): 1000000 | U+16B5F (): 100000000 |
| U+16B60 (): 10000000000 | U+16B61 (): 1000000000000 | U+16E80 (): 0 | U+16E81 (): 1 | U+16E82 (): 2 |
| U+16E83 (): 3 | U+16E84 (): 4 | U+16E85 (): 5 | U+16E86 (): 6 | U+16E87 (): 7 |
| U+16E88 (): 8 | U+16E89 (): 9 | U+16E8A (): 10 | U+16E8B (): 11 | U+16E8C (): 12 |
| U+16E8D (): 13 | U+16E8E (): 14 | U+16E8F (): 15 | U+16E90 (): 16 | U+16E91 (): 17 |
| U+16E92 (): 18 | U+16E93 (): 19 | U+16E94 (): 1 | U+16E95 (): 2 | U+16E96 (): 3 |
| U+1D2E0 (): 0 | U+1D2E1 (): 1 | U+1D2E2 (): 2 | U+1D2E3 (): 3 | U+1D2E4 (): 4 |
| U+1D2E5 (): 5 | U+1D2E6 (): 6 | U+1D2E7 (): 7 | U+1D2E8 (): 8 | U+1D2E9 (): 9 |
| U+1D2EA (): 10 | U+1D2EB (): 11 | U+1D2EC (): 12 | U+1D2ED (): 13 | U+1D2EE (): 14 |
| U+1D2EF (): 15 | U+1D2F0 (): 16 | U+1D2F1 (): 17 | U+1D2F2 (): 18 | U+1D2F3 (): 19 |
| U+1D360 (): 1 | U+1D361 (): 2 | U+1D362 (): 3 | U+1D363 (): 4 | U+1D364 (): 5 |
| U+1D365 (): 6 | U+1D366 (): 7 | U+1D367 (): 8 | U+1D368 (): 9 | U+1D369 (): 10 |
| U+1D36A (): 20 | U+1D36B (): 30 | U+1D36C (): 40 | U+1D36D (): 50 | U+1D36E (): 60 |
| U+1D36F (): 70 | U+1D370 (): 80 | U+1D371 (): 90 | U+1D372 (): 1 | U+1D373 (): 2 |
| U+1D374 (): 3 | U+1D375 (): 4 | U+1D376 (): 5 | U+1D377 (): 1 | U+1D378 (): 5 |
| U+1D7CE (): 0 | U+1D7CF (): 1 | U+1D7D0 (): 2 | U+1D7D1 (): 3 | U+1D7D2 (): 4 |
| U+1D7D3 (): 5 | U+1D7D4 (): 6 | U+1D7D5 (): 7 | U+1D7D6 (): 8 | U+1D7D7 (): 9 |
| U+1D7D8 (): 0 | U+1D7D9 (): 1 | U+1D7DA (): 2 | U+1D7DB (): 3 | U+1D7DC (): 4 |
| U+1D7DD (): 5 | U+1D7DE (): 6 | U+1D7DF (): 7 | U+1D7E0 (): 8 | U+1D7E1 (): 9 |
| U+1D7E2 (): 0 | U+1D7E3 (): 1 | U+1D7E4 (): 2 | U+1D7E5 (): 3 | U+1D7E6 (): 4 |
| U+1D7E7 (): 5 | U+1D7E8 (): 6 | U+1D7E9 (): 7 | U+1D7EA (): 8 | U+1D7EB (): 9 |
| U+1D7EC (): 0 | U+1D7ED (): 1 | U+1D7EE (): 2 | U+1D7EF (): 3 | U+1D7F0 (): 4 |
| U+1D7F1 (): 5 | U+1D7F2 (): 6 | U+1D7F3 (): 7 | U+1D7F4 (): 8 | U+1D7F5 (): 9 |
| U+1D7F6 (): 0 | U+1D7F7 (): 1 | U+1D7F8 (): 2 | U+1D7F9 (): 3 | U+1D7FA (): 4 |
| U+1D7FB (): 5 | U+1D7FC (): 6 | U+1D7FD (): 7 | U+1D7FE (): 8 | U+1D7FF (): 9 |
| U+1E8C7 (): 1 | U+1E8C8 (): 2 | U+1E8C9 (): 3 | U+1E8CA (): 4 | U+1E8CB (): 5 |
| U+1E8CC (): 6 | U+1E8CD (): 7 | U+1E8CE (): 8 | U+1E8CF (): 9 | U+1E950 (): 0 |
| U+1E951 (): 1 | U+1E952 (): 2 | U+1E953 (): 3 | U+1E954 (): 4 | U+1E955 (): 5 |
| U+1E956 (): 6 | U+1E957 (): 7 | U+1E958 (): 8 | U+1E959 (): 9 | U+1EC71 (): 1 |
| U+1EC72 (): 2 | U+1EC73 (): 3 | U+1EC74 (): 4 | U+1EC75 (): 5 | U+1EC76 (): 6 |
| U+1EC77 (): 7 | U+1EC78 (): 8 | U+1EC79 (): 9 | U+1EC7A (): 10 | U+1EC7B (): 20 |
| U+1EC7C (): 30 | U+1EC7D (): 40 | U+1EC7E (): 50 | U+1EC7F (): 60 | U+1EC80 (): 70 |
| U+1EC81 (): 80 | U+1EC82 (): 90 | U+1EC83 (): 100 | U+1EC84 (): 200 | U+1EC85 (): 300 |
| U+1EC86 (): 400 | U+1EC87 (): 500 | U+1EC88 (): 600 | U+1EC89 (): 700 | U+1EC8A (): 800 |
| U+1EC8B (): 900 | U+1EC8C (): 1000 | U+1EC8D (): 2000 | U+1EC8E (): 3000 | U+1EC8F (): 4000 |
| U+1EC90 (): 5000 | U+1EC91 (): 6000 | U+1EC92 (): 7000 | U+1EC93 (): 8000 | U+1EC94 (): 9000 |
| U+1EC95 (): 10000 | U+1EC96 (): 20000 | U+1EC97 (): 30000 | U+1EC98 (): 40000 | U+1EC99 (): 50000 |
| U+1EC9A (): 60000 | U+1EC9B (): 70000 | U+1EC9C (): 80000 | U+1EC9D (): 90000 | U+1EC9E (): 100000 |
| U+1EC9F (): 200000 | U+1ECA0 (): 100000 | U+1ECA1 (): 10000000 | U+1ECA2 (): 20000000 | U+1ECA3 (): 1 |
| U+1ECA4 (): 2 | U+1ECA5 (): 3 | U+1ECA6 (): 4 | U+1ECA7 (): 5 | U+1ECA8 (): 6 |
| U+1ECA9 (): 7 | U+1ECAA (): 8 | U+1ECAB (): 9 | U+1ECAD (): 0.25 | U+1ECAE (): 0.5 |
| U+1ECAF (): 0.75 | U+1ECB1 (): 1 | U+1ECB2 (): 2 | U+1ECB3 (): 10000 | U+1ECB4 (): 100000 |
| U+1F100 (): 0 | U+1F101 (): 0 | U+1F102 (): 1 | U+1F103 (): 2 | U+1F104 (): 3 |
| U+1F105 (): 4 | U+1F106 (): 5 | U+1F107 (): 6 | U+1F108 (): 7 | U+1F109 (): 8 |
| U+1F10A (): 9 | U+1F10B (): 0 | U+1F10C (): 0 | U+2F890 (): 9 |  |

Probably your browser probably won't be able to render lots of the above characters without installing more fonts, but you'll still see some interesting letters