# convert char array to int array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, char, int

I have this array

```
char[] A = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

And I want to convert it to int[]

```
int[] Aint=[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Any ideas?

I just started programming

Thanks

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve this problem yourself?  What problems are you having with those attempts?  Do you know how to convert one `char` to it's corresponding `int` value?  Do you know how to create a new array based on another array's values?

Answer (score 37):

Another option, using [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int[] Aint = Array.ConvertAll(A, c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far because it is extremely easier to read and understand at a glance. It's practically written in plain English.

Comment: Is there any reason why you used `Array.ConvertAll` instead of `Select(…).ToArray()`? I'm asking because the latter seems to be much more in vogue nowadays (and your lambda expression requires C# 3 anyway).

Comment: @Douglas: `Array.ConvertAll` is just more efficient than `Select..ToArray` since it  pre-allocates a correctly-sized array and doesn't do any resizing. It's also readable/explicit as Gray has already mentioned.

Comment: @Douglas: Also, it works already with .NET 2 even with the lambda.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, I agree it's more efficient in that respect. By mentioning C# 3, I meant that it requires the same version of C# (and .NET) as LINQ would.

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I agree that it's much more verbose for a new developer.

Comment: Btw, if anybody else wonders why `Char.GetNumericValue` returns a `double` instead of an `int`(isn't it a single digit?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2867132/284240

Comment: Sadly, this API is not available in .NET Standard 1.x, so it is not available as a cross-framework solution.

Comment: @NightOwl888: you are still on .NET 1.x?? This method is available since .NET 2, so since 2005

Comment: Nope. [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is the replacement for PCL, and in order to support .NET Core 1.x you must be on .NET Standard 1.x. As you can see [here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Array.ConvertAll%3CTInput,TOutput%3E(TInput(),Converter%3CTInput,TOutput%3E)), `Array.ConvertAll` is missing from .NET Standard and .NET Core 1.x (the numbers displayed are the minimum version).

Comment: Also `var a = Array.ConvertAll(text.ToCharArray(), c => int.Parse(c.ToString()));`

Answer (score 11):

To get the numeric value of a digit character (`'0'` to `'9'`), you can simply subtract the codepoint of `'0'` from its own.

```
int[] Aint = A.Select(a => a - '0').ToArray();
```

The digit characters are assigned consecutive codepoints. `'0'` has codepoint `48`; `'1'` has codepoint `49`; and so on until `'9'`, which has codepoint `57`. Thus, when you subtract two digit characters, you would get the same result as if you were subtracting their numeric values. Subtracting `'0'` from any digit would give you the latter's absolute value.

Comment: You need to have the **System.Linq** namespace included in your code because of the use of the Select method. You can do this by adding `using System.Linq` to the top of your code.

Comment: @Krige: You're right. Visual Studio 2013 includes it automatically for you when you create a new class file.

Answer (score 6):

Add a using statement for `using System.Linq;` then you can do the following:

```
int[] Aint = A.Select(i => Int32.Parse(i.ToString())).ToArray();
```

You will get an exception if an element in `A` cannot be parsed.

Comment: Concise is usually good but not so much for someone who has "just started programming".

Comment: Well he didn't ask for a specific implementation (for loop, while loop, etc) and I like Linq so that's how I implemented it.

Answer (score 4):

Please do Like this

```
  char[] A = {'1', '2', '3', '4'};
  int[] Aint = new int[A.Length];      
  for (int i = 0;i < A.Length;i++)
  {
      Aint[i] = Convert.ToInt32(A[i].ToString()); 
  }
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32, small mistake in solution.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of Linq should do the trick:

```
int[] Aint = A.Select(c => c - 48).ToArray(); // or c - '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
int[] Aint = A.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

This will select all character array as string, converts them to array, then return an integer of array.