# string word separated by characters and insert into int array

Tags: c#, split

I have the following `String word = "12345";` I want to split each character and insert this into an int array

like this-

`int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

whats the fastest and easiest way to do this ?

Comment: Some search on the internet? There are thousand topics out there to split a string, convert a character to integer. Everythings out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert char array to int array c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587186/convert-char-array-to-int-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

Try using *Linq*:

```
  String word = "12345";

  int[] array = word
    .Select(c => c - '0') // fastest conversion
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is happening in that Select command?

Comment: @jpaugh78: `c` is `char` and after subtracting `0` `Select` returns integer difference between `c` and `0` which is 0 for `0`, 1 for `1` ... 9 for `9`

Comment: okay, I think that makes sense.  I don't often deal with char, so it was a new concept for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
String word = "12345";
int[] array = word.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a int array from a String.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
    /// <returns>an Int Array</returns>
    public static IObservable<IEnumerable<int>> StringToIntArray(this string source)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<int>>(sub =>
        {
            var sourceAsStringArray = source.ToCharArray().Select(x => x.ToString());
            var l = new List<int>();
            foreach (var s in sourceAsStringArray)
            {
                int output = -1;
                if (int.TryParse(s, out output))
                {
                    l.Add(output);
                }
            }

            sub.OnNext(l);
            sub.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }

}

private async void Test()
    {
       var a = await "12345".StringToIntArray();
       var b = await "1a234b5".StringToIntArray();
       var invalid = await "IAmNotANumber".StringToIntArray();
    }
```