# convert string to int[] returning different values

Tags: c#, int

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter first array");
        string firstArray = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second array");
        string secondArray = Console.ReadLine();

        //int[] first = new int[] { 1, 5, 8 };
        //int[] second = new int[] { 2, 4, 9 };
        int[] first = firstArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
        int[] second = secondArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Getting a user to enter an array. When I try to convert the string value to an actual array the numbers are different.
Example if '1' is entered for the first array. '49' appears in the [] first

Comment: Because the character `1` has the Unicode code point `49`. Please read [ask] and elaborate what exactly you want to do. In what format does your user enter an array? Then split the input properly to obtain the individual numerical values. Then parse _those_ strings to numbers.

Comment: `char`  `'1'` it's `49` in `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert char array to int array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587186/convert-char-array-to-int-array-c-sharp)

Comment: The fundamental question is: "what do the input lines contain?" One number or several numbers speprated by spaces or commas? The next question is: "what is the expected output?". And last but not least: what is your actual question? You need to clarify these points, before we can give you an accurate answer. Otherwise we can only guess what your intention is.

Answer (score 1):

`firstArray.Select` will treat your string as a `char[]`. So, as SeM said "char ch = '1' it's 49 in int".

You will need to split the string first. For instance, if it's comma separated you should do:

```cs
firstArray.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```