# How to compare number zero programmatically when the keyboard language is changed from english to other language in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to compare zero that is coming from TextBox as string for removing it from front in c#.

```
 private string RemoveLeadingZeros(string str)//TextBox.Text
        {
            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Trim().Length; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] == '0')//This comparison fails if i change the keyboard language from english to some other language ex. chinese
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return (index != -1) ? str.Substring(index) : "0";
        }
```

So, for example if the string is "0001" it should return 1. This method fails if we change the keyboard language other than English (Example:chinese).

How can we compare the zero irrespective of the language changed from keyboard from English to some other language?

Comment: Can't you just convert it to an integer and back to a string using the default locale?

Comment: Can you just parse the number out using `Integer.Parse` with the correct culture setting?

Comment: try `String.Equals(str1, str2 , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: `int.Parse(str[i], new CultureInfo("zh-CN"))` works for standard Arabic numerals. What kind of numeric input used if the keyboard layout has changed?

Comment: @LoztInSpace culture setting dont have a role here, it is still set to english even when the keyboard language is changed.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto we dont know the keyboard language we need to achieve it at runtime this comparison.

Comment: @Bathsheba can u illustrate with a code snippet?

Comment: @wdc what is str1 and str2, if str1 is character coming from string and str is "0", this doesn't work.

Comment: Those are strings that you are comparing, if you have character you can call `toString()` like this: 
`String.Equals(char1.ToString(), char2.toString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: Your method does not do what it says: if there are one or more leading zeros, the last zero remains in the result string; if there is no leading zero, the result string is "0". Besides that, the only way a non-English input language could fail this method is if for example the Chinese keyboard produces a different zero than the English one, i.e. a zero for which ``(int)'0'`` is not 48…

Comment: I found a solution to fix it: char.ToNumericValue() converts it to double representation of the number so we can use that to convert the original string and then check with '0'. Thanks everyone for sharing their view... If anyone find alternative solution let me know.

Comment: @dumetrulo in chinese, there is a different keyboard used and '0' is represented in unicode and valus is not 48 it is near to 65000.. u can try that in your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked a font containing CJK characters (Microsoft JhengHei on Windows 10), and inferred from it that a Chinese keyboard layout would return full-width numbers (starting at U+FF10). As other keyboard layouts may provide even different numbers, it would appear that the best choice is to use the `char.GetNumericValue()` method (see also [What's the deal with char.GetNumericValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866738/whats-the-deal-with-char-getnumericvalue)).

*EDIT:* `Substring()` with a single parameter returns the same string if the index is 0. Added trimming as in the original post, changed the method name to reflect it, and made it an extension method.

With that, your method would look as follows:

```
private static string TrimAndRemoveLeadingZeros(this string str)
{
    int idx = 0;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;
    str = str.Trim();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = (int)char.GetNumericValue(str[i]);
        if (num == 0) idx++;
        else break;
    }
    return str.Substring(idx);
}
```